# I am trying to parse an XML file using C# in the .NET environment and it keeps skipping over elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

So this is how a portion of the XML I am trying to parse looks like:

```
<azsa:Views>
   <azsa:Spatial_Array>
      <azsa:Spatial>
         <azsa:ViewName>Spatial</azsa:ViewName>
            <azsa:BBox>
               <azsa:PointLo>
                 <azsa:x>0</azsa:x>
                 <azsa:y>0</azsa:y>
                 <azsa:z>0</azsa:z>
                </azsa:PointLo>
               <azsa:PointHi>
                 <azsa:x>2925</azsa:x>
                 <azsa:y>3375</azsa:y>
                 <azsa:z>2775</azsa:z>
               </azsa:PointHi>
             </azsa:BBox>
       </azsa:Spatial>
    </azsa:Spatial_Array>
</azsa:Views>
```

I have to read the x,y and z coordinates for both PointHi and PointLo

I was using the XMLReader() class to perform the task.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);

 while (reader.Read())
 {
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:Views");
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:Spatial_Array");
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:Spatial");
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:ViewName");
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:BBox");
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:PointLo");
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:x");
   low[0] = (int)(Double.Parse(reader.ReadElementString()));
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:y");
   low[1] = (int)(Double.Parse(reader.ReadElementString()));
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:z");
   low[2] = (int)(Double.Parse(reader.ReadElementString()));
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:PointHi");
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:x");
   high[0] = (int)(Double.Parse(reader.ReadElementString()));
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:y");
   high[1] = (int)(Double.Parse(reader.ReadElementString()));
   reader.ReadToFollowing("azsa:z");
   high[2] = (int)(Double.Parse(reader.ReadElementString()));
}
```

The reader works perfectly until it gets to the first x in the PointLo and then it just skips to the y in PointHi instead. I have tried using descendants, subtrees and readinnerxml but it still does the same thing.

NOTE: 1. There is more code in the while loop for reading the remaining part of the XML but was not necessary for this problem so I have not included it in the post. 
2. Changing the way the XML is organized is not possible because that's how they are required to be stored for the task I am performing.
3. XMLReader is the preferable method as I am dealing with a large number of documents and there is no scope for having this use cache memory.

Comment: Side note: reason 3 in the post is not convincing as written - "a large number of documents" do not justify such painful API as XmlReader in my book, but maybe you mean "a number of large documents" where indeed Reader may be good choice.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant a large number of large documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a fairly similar issue a while back when reading subtrees.  The solution in that scenario was to dispose the subtree XmlReaders.  Granted, the situation here is slightly different, but could you consider an approach such as below (note that I removed the element prefixes for simplicity of testing, as well as read in the XML string rather than a file)?

It is certainly ugly looking, but this was more a proof of concept and could be tidied up a bit.  It is also lacking the appropriate error checking, but again this was more for demonstration purposes.  It does at least parse out the different point values.

As a side note, I think perhaps a lot of the ugliness could be abstracted away by making classes to represent the different components (or objects) within the XML stream, and making those classes responsible for parsing out their own properties.

Just one way (of many I'm sure) to skin a cat...

```
private void ParseXml(string xml)
{
    double[] low = null;
    double[] hi = null;

    using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
        {
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;

                if (xmlReader.Name == "PointLo")
                {
                    low = ParsePoint(xmlReader);
                }
                else if (xmlReader.Name == "PointHi")
                {
                    hi = ParsePoint(xmlReader);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private double[] ParsePoint(XmlReader xmlReader)
{
    double[] point = new double[3];

    using (XmlReader pointReader = xmlReader.ReadSubtree())
    {
        while (pointReader.Read())
        {
            if (pointReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element) continue;

            if (pointReader.Name == "x")
            {
                point[0] = GetDimensionValue(pointReader);
            }
            else if (pointReader.Name == "y")
            {
                point[1] = GetDimensionValue(pointReader);
            }
            else if (pointReader.Name == "z")
            {
                point[2] = GetDimensionValue(pointReader);
            }
        }
    }

    return point;
}

private double GetDimensionValue(XmlReader reader)
{
    using (XmlReader dimensionReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
    {
        dimensionReader.Read();

        return reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: SO this actually works better than mine did, but its still skipping over the y values for some reason. I am trying to figure out how to fix that but it is still more than I had, so thank you so much!

Comment: When it gets to y it thinks that the pointReader.NodeType is not an element so it skips over it.

Comment: I fixed it completely. I just changed the way it proceeded with its pointReader.Read. So it does that in the else part of the if else loop instead of the while loop and the while loop uses a flag value as a conditional. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

So as I mentioned in the comments to manderson's solution that for some reason it does not see the y element as an element and instead sees it as a text element, I made the following changes to the while loop in ParsePoint()

```
                 while (pointReader.Read())
                  {
                    if (pointReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element || pointReader.NodeType== XmlNodeType.Text)
                     {

                      if (pointReader.Name == "azsa:x")
                       {
                          point[0] = pointReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
                       }
                      else if (pointReader.Name == "")
                       {
                          point[1] = Double.Parse(pointReader.Value);
                       }
                     else if (pointReader.Name == "azsa:z")
                       {
                     point[2] = pointReader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
                       }
                    }
                 }
```

While I am not claiming that this is the ideal way to do this, it works for the XML files I am dealing with. I also removed the GetDimensionValue method and just do the reading of the values/element contents in this method itself.